# Convergence of $f(u_n) \to f(u)$ when $u_n \to u$ in $L^p$/Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I got a function $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which is such that $0 \leq f \leq 1$ and it is a smooth function. Suppose $u_n \to u$ in $H^1(\Omega)$. $\Omega$ is a bounded smooth domain

What is the best convergence I can get for $f(u_n) \to f(u)$?

Using the DCT I can obtain $f(u_n) \to f(u)$ in $L^p(\Omega)$ for every $p < \infty$. Is there something better like $p=\infty$ in this case?

Comment: to clarify: $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^1$, correct?

Comment: @supinf Not necessarily it can be $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy We have the pointwise convergence since $f$ is continuous, of $f(u_n) \to f(u)$ a.e. Also $f(u_n)$ is dominated by $1$ which is $L^p$ integrable. Hence DCT applies no??

Comment: The keyword to search for is [Nemitskij operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemytskii_operator).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How does that work ?

Comment: @StopUsingFacebook: Is $f'$ bounded as well?

Comment: @gerw Yes let us assume it. maybe MVT helsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dimension of $\Omega$ is bigger than $1$, you cannot get convergence in $L^\infty(\Omega)$ without further assumptions.

Here is a counterexample:

Let us take $v \in H^1(\Omega) \setminus L^\infty(\Omega)$ such that $v(\Omega) = [0,\infty)$ and set $u_n = v/n$. Then, $u_n \to 0$ in $H^1(\Omega)$. With $f(x) = \sin(x)$ one can check that $f(u_n)$ takes values in all of $[0,1]$. Hence, it cannot converge in $L^\infty(\Omega)$.